# Convert DOCX to PDF - Java

Tags: java

I generate a docx document in runtime and I want to convert it to PDF without actually saving the file locally

```
public byte[] convertToPDF(byte[] docxDocument) {
    try {
        InputStream doc = new ByteArrayInputStream(docxDocument);
        XWPFDocument xwpfDocument = new XWPFDocument(doc);
        PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
        OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(xwpfDocument, out, options);
        //return data; ???
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not convert docx to PDF", e);
    }
}
```

`PdfConverter` is void. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `return out.toByteArray();` - [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) are your friend.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to say `PdfConverter` is void. That's a class name. I guess you mean the return type of `PdfConverter::convert` is void.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **out** which keeps the converted data

```
return out.toByteArray();
```